# A a criterion for continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a topological space. Prove that a real-valued function $f$ on $X$ is continuous if and only if for every real number $a$ the sets $\{x \in X: f(x) < a \}$ and $\{x \in X: f(x) > a \}$ are open in $X$.

My argument: If $f$ is continuous, then for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the sets $f^{-1}(-\infty, a) = \{x \in X: f(x) < a \}$ and $f^{-1}(a, \infty) = \{x \in X: f(x) > a \}$ are open in $X$.

On the other hand, let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $A = f^{-1}(-\infty, a)$ and $B = f^{-1}(a, \infty)$ are open in $X$.Then $A \cup B = f^{-1}(-\infty, \infty)$ is also open. Let $O$ be an open in $\mathbb{R}$. Then we know that $O = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(a_{n}, b_{n})$ and since $f^{-1}(O) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f^{-1}((a_{n}, b_{n}))$ and arbitary union of open sets in a topological space is open, it suffices to show that $f^{-1}((a_{n}, b_{n}))$ is open. If $a_{n} = -\infty$ or $b_{n} = \infty$ then the result follows by the hypothesis, so we only check for $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ finite.

Let $x \in f^{-1}((a_{n}, b_{n}))$. Suppose $U$ is an open subset in $X$ containing $x$. We need to show that $U \subseteq f^{-1}((a_{n}, b_{n}))$. Suppose not. Then there exists $y \in U$ with $y \notin f^{-1}((a_{n}, b_{n}))$.

Then $f(y)\in (-\infty, a_{n}) \cup (b_{n}, \infty)$.
Then $y \in f^{-1}((-\infty, a_{n}) \cup (b_{n}, \infty)) \implies U \subset f^{-1}((-\infty, a_{n}) \cup (b_{n}, \infty))$. But this implies that $x \in f^{-1}((-\infty, a_{n}) \cup (b_{n}, \infty))$, which is a contradiction since $x \in f^{-1}((a_{n}, b_{n}))$ also.

Of course, there is an issue here to address, which is the case: $f(y) = a_{n}, b_{n}$. I hope there is a way of settling this.

Comment: Please state you are using what definition of continuity, so that the reader does not have to figure out what that is by reading through the words.

Comment: The pre-image of an open set is open.

Comment: Next, please state it in the first place, if you want to get more attention and receive better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f^{-1}(\leftarrow,a)$ and $f^{-1}(a,\rightarrow)$ are open in $X$ for each $a\in R. $ Then $f^{-1}(a,b)=(f^{-1}(\leftarrow,b))\cap (f^{-1}(a,\rightarrow))$ is open in $X$ for any $a,b \in R. $ Every $S\subset R$, which is open in $R$, is equal to $\cup T$ where $T$ is a family of bounded open intervals, so $f^{-1}S=\cup \{f^{-1} t : t\in T\}$ is open in $X$.

Comment: In general , for a function $f:X\to Y, $  and a sub-base $B$ for $Y, $ if $f^{-1}b$ is open in $X$ for each $b\in B$ then $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open. Take $x \in f^{-1}(V)$. Then $f(x) \in V$. Since $V$ is open, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $f(x) \in (y - \epsilon, y +\epsilon) \subset V \implies x \in f^{-1}(y-\epsilon, y +\epsilon) = f^{-1}(y -\epsilon, \infty) \cap f^{-1}(-\infty, y + \epsilon)$ so that by the hypothesis $f^{-1}(y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon)$ is open and $x \in f^{-1}(y -\epsilon, y + \epsilon) \subset f^{-1}(V)$. Thus for any $x \in f^{-1}(V)$, we found a neighborhood of $x$ that lies in $f^{-1}(V)$ and we can conclude that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open. Hence, $f$ is continuous.